# Error after upgrading Bugzilla from 4.0 to 4.0.2

Tags: permissions, patch, bugzilla

I had a good working new installation of Bugzilla 4.0.

I have upgraded to version 4.0.2 using the [patch](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.0/en/html/upgrade.html).

Everything went ok until I had to clear the **shutdownhtml** field in the Params page

```
http://192.168.0.22/bugzilla/editparams.cgi
```

Doing that, gave the error on the screen:

```
Software error:

Error reading ./data/params: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 323.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/bugzilla/editparams.cgi line 28.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/bugzilla/editparams.cgi line 28.
For help, please send mail to the webmaster (webmaster@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

Ok, it's definitely a permission error. I have set /var/www/bugzilla as follow:

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 www-data www-data    4096 2011-09-22 12:58 bugzilla/
```

Q1: What user should have done the patch upgrade?  I used Administrator with sudo.  -- was that wrong?
Q2: What should be the settings for the directory structure and files?  isn't 755 and chown/chgrp www-data is enough?

ANSWER:
I had to change the following directory in order to fix the permission rights

chmod 777 /var/www/bugzilla/data/template/template/en/default  (for all changes to be written)
chmod 777 /var/www/bugzilla/data/params

This works, but still I don't know how it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chmod 777 /var/www/bugzilla/data/template/template/en/default
```

for all changes to be written

```
chmod 777 /var/www/bugzilla/data/params
```